# Azure VM Custom Script Extension: detaled output status is not available on portal

Tags: azure

My script just simply makes a few outputs with `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`. Which I can see when I grab output status from CLI with `Get-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension` and checking `$output.SubStatuses[0].Message`.

But, some reason, when I select view extension on web portal, I don't see *View detailed status* link. Everywhere on internet people referring to it, but it is missing for me some reason, it is just a blank space for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the description NuGet is missing which is the dependency. Please try to fullfil the dependency or you can try to run the script directly to the just to be sure that might help.